# Combine two android projects with one login

Tags: android, authentication, project, integrate

I'm working on a project. In that, there are two applications. My new requirement is combine both apps into one. I have the two projects with me. Does anyone know how to merge those two projects into a single one? Then there is only one app after the modification is done. Login process should identify which application to load.

Answer (score -2):

Well things may be complicated , I'm new too android but done my first mini project, what you need to do is try importing each class file and xml file one by one after completely understanding its resources and interfaces, make your new main class file giving an option to launch that particular activity chosen from ui to trigger one of your apps.

Comment: Thanks Lohoris But I already knew that..ya that will be really complicated. That is why I asked another easy way to do that? Thanks anyway.